# Objectify Google DataSore Query

Tags: java, objectify

Here's the thing :-)
We have two classes, `Appointment` and `Hairdresser`, both having the same, one ancestor (a static final Key: `topParent`) representing the `HairSalon` Key. The `Appointment` contains the `Hairdresser` like this:

```
    @Parent
    public Key parent; 
    public Key hairdresserKey;`
```

but when we try to filter out the appointment, it doesn't come up with a result. The parent in the `hairdresserKey == null`, that might be a clue, but we're kind of stuck now.

So can someone please tell us what's wrong with this query?

Thanks a lot!

```
        appointment.hairdresserKey = new Key<Hairdresser>(topParent, Hairdresser.class, appointment.hairdresser.id);
    appointment.parent = topParent;

    Key<Hairdresser> queryKey = new Key<Hairdresser>(topParent, Hairdresser.class, appointment.hairdresser.id);

    Objectify ofyTransaction = ObjectifyService.beginTransaction();
    try {

        List<Key<Appointment>> previousTimeSlotOneHour = ofyTransaction.query(Appointment.class)
                .ancestor(topParent)
                .filter("hairdresserKey", appointment.hairdresserKey)
                .filter("timeSlot", appointment.timeSlot.getPreviousTimeSlot())
                .filter("LENGTH", 1.0d).listKeys();
```

To clearify some more, this is how Appointment set up:

```
@Unindexed
```

public class Appointment implements Serializable {

```
@Id
public Long id;
@Indexed
public TimeSlot timeSlot;

@Transient
public WorkDay workDay;

@Transient
public Customer customer;
public Key customerKey;

public int END_TIME_HOUR;
public int END_TIME_MINUTES;

@Indexed
public TREATMENT treatment = TREATMENT.TREATMENT_CUT;
public int revisionNumber = -1;

/* QUERY Fields */
@Indexed
private String stringDate;
private double LENGTH;

@Parent
public Key parent;
private Date date;

@Transient
public Hairdresser hairdresser;
public Key hairdresserKey;
```

Comment: Have you created both a multi-property index across {ancestor, hairdresserKey, timeSlot, LENGTH} *and* single-property indexes for all of those fields?

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

This is almost certainly an indexing issue. In order for that query to work, you must define two indexes:

A single-property index on referenceKeyToC
A multi-property index on {ancestor, referenceKeyToC}
In Objectify 3.x, properties have single-property indexes by default, but if you have added @Unindexed to the class B then you need to put @Indexed on referenceKeyToC.
The multi-property index is defined in datastore-indexes.xml. If you run this query in dev mode, the environment should provide you with the snippet of xml needed.

That did the trick! Thanks for pointing in the right direction!